# How to listen HTTP response and apply preloader?

Tags: angular, angular5

I use HTTP library for executing request to server in my SPA like this:

```
public get(cls: number): Observable<any[]> {

    const data = {

    };

    return this.http.post(null, data)
      .map(result => {
        return result.json().result;
      })
      .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
  }
```

Let's assume we have a preloader service, that is started when request leaves and stops when response comes.

How to bind this service to HTTP? Exactly, I can subscribe on Observer response like:

```
preloader.start();
get(1).subscribe(data => {}, error => {
   preloader.stop();
});
```

But it is not fit for me, I want to make this more universal and more abstract

Comment: Why don't you use Interceptors?

Comment: Really good idea, and inject preloader there?

Comment: Yeah I mean you can do that. You'll just have to check where exactly(for which specific request) you want to start them and where you want to stop the,.

Comment: I dont understand is ppreloder directive or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use **ng-http-loader** library, to install it:

```
$ npm install ng-http-loader --save / yarn add ng-http-loader
```

This package provides an HTTP Interceptor, and some spinner components. The HTTP interceptor listens to all HTTP requests and shows a spinner / loader indicator during pending http requests.

usage:

```
From your Angular AppModule:

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
[...]
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; <============
import { NgHttpLoaderModule } from 'ng-http-loader'; <============

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule, <============ (Perform http requests with this module)
    NgHttpLoaderModule, <============
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In your app.component.html, simply add:

```
<ng-http-loader></ng-http-loader>
```

Here's the full documentation: https://github.com/mpalourdio/ng-http-loader

Comment: For some reason, I don't really think using a third party package for this is really worth it. Just increases the bundle size without much added advantage.